Web vitals onINP reporting elements that do not have any click functionality or handlers attached
In order to improve INP of my application, I integrated web-vitals@3/dist/web-vitals.attribution.iife.js to get field data and work on actual interactions causing poor INP score. However in my data I see a lot of elements reported actually dont have click functionality/handlers attached. For instance there are many div/span/p elements reported in the report. What is the reason behind such a behaviour. This basically makes improvement exercise very ineffective and lengthy. I am collecting attribution.eventTarget for the elements on which interactions happen.
attribution.eventTarget

function sendToAnalytics({name, value, rating, attribution}) {
  // here I am creating req payload with element as attribution.eventTarget 
}

onINP(sendToAnalytics);


There's a few reasons why seemingly non-interactive targets can be marked as the INP target, the two most common of which are:

In Chrome 125 - 128 we stopped reporting scroll start elements, which was a common reason for this—particularly on mobile. That's fully rolled out now but, as it's a fairly recent change, you may still be getting reports from those who haven't upgraded their browsers or other Chromium-based browsers which haven't incorporated this change yet. Check if this is falling over time and/or which browsers are still reporting this.

Global event handlers that run on all elements at body level are quite common, often because the framework used registers them at a high level and then acts upon the element affected. Similarly, some tools like Google Tag Manager or the like can also register global event handlers. Check to ensure your div/span/p elements don't actually have inherited event handlers


I also note you're using v3 of the library and would strongly recommend upgrading to v4 (and v5 soon!) so ensure you have the latest improvements to the library.

Thanks for the detailed and insightful answer to my question. One more thing I would like to clarify, does adding a background-color on an element's active and focus state help improve INP?

Basically no as INP doesn't need a paint but just measures when the browser is next able to paint. But it would be good UX to give some indication (and it would make it also more obvious to you for debugging if something changed). See also here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals/issues/542#issuecomment-2401803431
